# export RDLC in HTML format

Tags: .net, html, rdlc

Is there any way to export RDLC reports in HTML format in visual studio 2010?

there are only 3 available format(excel, word, pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating a Custom Export to Excel for ReportViewer (rdlc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494009/creating-a-custom-export-to-excel-for-reportviewer-rdlc)

by default, supported formats does not include html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839(v=vs.80).aspx

However, you can read excel or other data and generate html output.