# RDLC export large data having 1000+ pages ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am making one web application and i have used RDLC on some my page to purely export the data  to the user specific UI.

I am not using the reportviewer on the UI side to show the report preview, user just click the export button and in the code behind i am creating the object of reportviewer and binding, passing the data/parameter from there. After then just use the Render method of it to get the byte array and send it to the user. I have refer this link for it
[Creating a Custom Export to Excel for ReportViewer (rdlc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494009/creating-a-custom-export-to-excel-for-reportviewer-rdlc)

Now the real problem arises when i have large number of data to be exported around 1000+
I believe the render method is taking too much time and hence the browser (chrome) is showing the message of "No Data received" after 4-5 minutes.

So i was thinking that may i can export the data in chunks and then pass the streams to the user so user continuously getting the data. i came across the page of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837(v=vs.80).aspx where it uses "CreateStreamCallback" to create the stream while printing.

Is there anything such i can do for my purpose of exporting? Is there any other way to make this export smooth? I have use the RDLC because user wants the export in specific format and in various file format of DOC, PDF, XLS etc.

Thank you for your time. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Letting a web user wait that long may not be the best thing to do. Maybe you can just do the report creation in a separate thread and then notify the user with a link to the file that has been created once it's done?

Comment: @rikitikitik   Can i do this in web application? i dont have the idea about it. Can you point me some direction to go?