# Export Report Data To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I have two separate projects **MyApp.Reports** and **MyApp.WEB**

the MyApp.Reports containts only *.rdlc reports and MyApp.WEB is the ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor. I have a requirement to export the data from my report to Excel and let the user Download it, how can i load the data from my model to the Report and export it to an Excel file?

What i allready tried:

[Prototype MVC4 Razor ReportViewer? RDLC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609580/Prototype-MVC-Razor-ReportViewer-RDLC)  <-- Generates an image instead of PDF or Excel

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int OrderNr { get; set;}
  public string Title { get; set;}
}
```

Action:

```
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
      IEnumerable<MyModel> model = database.GetMyModelData(); //<-- returns list of data 
      ...
    }
```

Comment: "P.S. this is not a duplicate" - show exactly what you found and why you think that didn't apply. See for example [Creating a Custom Export to Excel for ReportViewer (rdlc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494009/creating-a-custom-export-to-excel-for-reportviewer-rdlc).

Comment: Your link uses report viewer from webforms as a said i want the user to see a download and in razor is there a way to not use webforms?

Comment: Here is a CodeProject page on using local ssrs reports from MVC. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609580/Prototype-MVC-Razor-ReportViewer-RDLC

Comment: Ill look at that once i get home thanks

Comment: Looks like your suggested link uses report to generate an Image, and even when i downloaded the sample and clicked on view as PDF it gives me an image and that's it, any more ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After tinkering with the CodeProject demo that **"Bradly Uffner"** gave me i managed to get the code working the way i wanted it to, you can download the demo project [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609580/Prototype-MVC-Razor-ReportViewer-RDLC). So here is what i came up with:

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Report in Excel Format", "ExportReport", new { ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel", FileType = "Excel" })

@Html.ActionLink("Download Report in PDF Format", "ExportReport", new { ContentType = "application/pdf", FileType = "pdf" })
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportReport(string FileType, string ContentType)
{
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
    localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Report1.rdlc");
    IList<WorldModel> customerList = new List<WorldModel>();

    // SOME DEMO DATA!
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Sweden", "2001", "1823"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Sweden", "2002", "1234"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Sweden", "2003", "9087"));

    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Denmark", "2001", "6793"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Denmark", "2002", "4563"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Denmark", "2003", "1897"));

    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Norway", "2001", "5632"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Norway", "2002", "9870"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Europe", "Norway", "2003", "2367"));

    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Asia", "India", "2001", "1980"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Asia", "India", "2002", "9765"));
    customerList.Add(new WorldModel("Asia", "India", "2003", "6789"));
    //DEMO DATA END

    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";

    //********** IF YOU NEED TO FILTER THE DATA ******************
    //var customerfilterList = from c in customerList
    //                         where c.Territory == territory
    //                         select c;
    //reportDataSource.Value = customerfilterList;
    //************************************************************

    reportDataSource.Value = customerList;

    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
    string reportType = FileType;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;
    //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType            
    //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx            
    string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + FileType + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);          
    return File(renderedBytes, ContentType, string.Format("NameOfFile.{0}",fileNameExtension));

}
```

I'm not sure if this will work if the reports are in a seperate project but i will try that also.

Resources:
Content Types [Here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)