# Alternatives to Render a report as CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, reportviewer, localreport

I need to Render a report as CSV, but I found in some forums that LocalReport don't render CSV. I have a lot of reports in rdlc, and change it would be very hard, I think.

I thougth to Render as Excel, get the bytes and transform it to CSV, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is some code:

```
if (FormatoRelatorioEnum.XLS == (FormatoRelatorioEnum)formatoRelatorio){
   bytes = lr.Render("Excel", deviceInfo);
   if (temMais || parte > 1){
      nomeArquivoDownload = "Relatorio_" + relatorioModel.nomeRelatorio + "_Parte_" + parte + ".xls";
   }
   else{
      nomeArquivoDownload = "Relatorio_" + relatorioModel.nomeRelatorio + ".xls";
   }
   contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
}
else if(FormatoRelatorioEnum.PDF == (FormatoRelatorioEnum)formatoRelatorio){
   bytes = lr.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
   nomeArquivoDownload = "Relatorio_" + relatorioModel.nomeRelatorio + ".pdf";
   contentType = "application/pdf";
}
else{
   bytes = lr.Render("CSV", deviceInfo);
   nomeArquivoDownload = "Relatorio_" + relatorioModel.nomeRelatorio + ".csv";
   contentType = "text/csv";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Custom Export to Excel for ReportViewer (rdlc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494009/creating-a-custom-export-to-excel-for-reportviewer-rdlc)

Comment: I can export to EXCEL, but I need to export to CSV

Comment: It isn't possible with `LocalReport`. The recommended solution is to write your own CSV output system. The next best is to use an SSRS report server which will support CSV. The worst might be to output Excel and then Office Automation to convert that to CSV, but that is extremely not recommended on a web server, and a bad idea on a desktop client as well.

Comment: There is any plugin to convert directely the data to csv format? If I have the bytes, I think that its okay to proceed.